# transactions using deuce stm

Tags: java, transactions, atomic

I am trying to revert object state on exceptions. My code is like::

```
public class DeuceTXTest
{
 @Atomic
 public void myTransactionMethod(HashMap<String, String> myHashMap)
         {
  myHashMap.put("s2", "two");
  if(8>5) 
                  throw new NullPointerException();
 }

  public static void main(String[] args){
   HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
   hashMap.put("s1", "one");
   System.out.println("Prior TX :: "+hashMap);
   DeuceTXTest txTest = new DeuceTXTest();
   try {
    txTest.myTransactionMethod(hashMap);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
   }
   System.out.println("Post TX :: "+hashMap);
  }
}
```

I added `-javaagent:myDir/deuceAgent.jar` as the VMArgument while running on eclipse.

Result Expected::

```
Prior TX :: {s1=one}
               java.lang.RuntimeException
               Post TX :: {s1=one}
```

Actual Result ::

```
Prior TX :: {s1=one}
       java.lang.RuntimeException
       Post TX :: {s2=two, s1=one}.
```

Also, please suggest me better examples on deuce to revert / restore object state on transaction rollback or when exception is thrown.

Comment: Use 4 indents to format your source code.

Answer (score 3):

Deuce semantic is commit on user Exception, same as with single global lock.
This was done like this since Exception in Java are legitimate flow control.

If you want to roll back the transaction you can throw TransactionException or AbrotTransactionException.

BTW, since you're using as part of your transaction a class that is part of the rt.jar (and loaded in the bootclasspath) you should offline instrument the rt.jar or at least this class as add it to the bootclassloader.

See: http://www.deucestm.org/documentation/getting-started

Comment: While it is Duece design decision to consider Commit on Exception, it feels odd from user point of view. STMs failure atomicity is lost as most of the people would use Exception on failure conditions..

Comment: Could you be more brief on your answer.. ie; What else I should do for running on deuce

Comment: "it feels odd from user point of view", why is it odd?
Deuce by design wanted to give the users same semantic as global lock.
Meaning assuming instead of @Atomic you would have used synchronized block. Then in this case you would have get an atomic behavior while an Exception wouldn't have rollback the code.